# Receive email with AWS SES without MX record

Tags: aws-sdk

I'll like to process incoming email on a specific email. In aws docs it says

Although you are not required to publish an MX record to receive mail through Amazon SES, if you don't publish the record, Amazon SES will receive mail for your domain only if you explicitly route it to Amazon SES.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-mx-record.html

How do I explicitly route email to SES?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After hours of research and failed attempts of having SES receive emails without the use of a MX record *(had set up an additional Route via gSuite / Google Apps)*, here is my best suggestion on how to go about this.

## Short Version

Create a subdomain and point its MX record to SES after inserting the TXT verification record.
 After creating the necessary ruleset to receive and save email from `any@sub.domain.com`, you can now have SES receive email from any email address you own *(even if it's not verified with SES)* by simply forwarding its emails to the SES enabled subdomain email address.

---

## Long Version

Unfortunately, it does still require an MX record, but check it out... 
You can create a custom subdomain on your primary domain and call it anything. In my case, I called it `ses.mydomain.com`
Next, I added my newly created subdomain to SES via the **Domains** link. 
Immediately upon adding it as a domain to SES, a pop-up window appears displaying the required `TXT verification record` and `MX mail record`.

Shortly after assigning these two DNS records to my subdomain, the subdomain is verified and able to receive email after setting a few quick rules via **Rule Sets**!

Here's the cool part - you can still have SES receive email from **any** email address you have access to.

### How you might ask?

**By just setting up a forwarder on the email address you do want to send to SES, by forwarding it to the SES-enabled subdomain email address.**

Meaning - If SES is able to receive email from `someone@ses.example.com`, but you want it to actually receive email from `someone-else@example.com`, then all you need to do is forward `someone-else@example.com` to `someone@ses.example.com`!

---

Remember, you still need to create the necessary rules to receive emails. [See this AWS Blog Post for more information](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-receive-and-process-incoming-email-with-amazon-ses/).

Comment: View my answer here for more details on creating the required Rule Set - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45004408/7666725

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the AWS SES's inbound endpoints:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-select

e.g. for US-EAST-1 the inbound endpoint is `inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. For receiving only you do not use SMTP endpoints. The procedure is pretty much the same using MX records or not: somewhere (in your DNS or in your mail handling system) you must point to a SES inbound endpoint.

For example, my MX records point to Google Apps, but using 'Hosts' and 'Routing' (inside Google Apps/Gmail options) I managed to relay only one recipient to SES. So every e-mail my domain receives goes to Gmail recipients as usual, except for one special_recipient@mydomain.com which I relayed to SES (which, in turn, goes to SNS then to SQS).

Comment: I am trying to forward emails from my outlook account to SES, Can I do it by just creating a forward rule ? if so what address I should be giving? Is it something@inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. If not can u help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181230/how-to-make-outlook-forward-email-to-aws-ses

Comment: @Jerry you can't do it with a regular forward rule. Instead, you have to **relay** it to another SMTP. Relay is a kind of "low-level redirect" that you can only do if you own a domain. So I can relay my company's email addresses that I use with G Suite (former Google Apps) but I can't relay my personal email@gmail.com. I believe that the same constraint will apply to Outlook.com as well.

Answer (score 1):

from:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-receive-and-process-incoming-email-with-amazon-ses/

Now you need to route your incoming email to SES for processing. You have two options here. You can set the domain’s MX (Mail Exchange) record to point to the SES SMTP endpoint in the region where you want to process incoming email. Or, you can configure your existing mail handling system to forward mail to the endpoint.

Comment: this may also be useful : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html

Comment: Hi, the link in the comment seem to be in the right direction but still, I don't understand if there should be a specific email I should forward the email to?

Comment: you prob need to add the domain and verify it, and the email address and verify it via the AWS console.. then you can send email directly to the endpoint SMTP server to those email addresses and it will accept the request for delivery to them.

Comment: Before you can send an email using Amazon SES, you must verify the address or domain that you are sending the email from to prove that you own it. If your account is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also need to verify any email addresses that you send emails to except for email addresses provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. You can verify an email address or domain by using the Amazon SES console or by using the Amazon SES API.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html

Comment: You can send email through Amazon SES by using a variety of SMTP-enabled programming languages and software. To learn more about the Amazon SES SMTP interface, click here.  here being -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html