# Recipient rule set to put emails into dynamic s3 bucket Amazon

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to set up amazon SES recipient rule set for putting emails into an s3 bucket. I have created an s3 bucket and I want these mails to sent into folders according to the email id. For example if an email is coming to **1@mydomain.com** it should go into **mytestbucket/1** and if it is coming to **2@mydomain.com** it should go into **mytestbucket/2**.

```
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(awsCredentials);
    ;
    if (sesClient != null) {
        CreateReceiptRuleRequest req = new CreateReceiptRuleRequest();
        req.withRuleSetName(ruleSetName);
        ReceiptRule rule = new ReceiptRule();
        rule.setEnabled(true);
        rule.setName(customerIdString + "-email");
        rule.withRecipients(customerIdString + "@" + mydomain.com);
        List<ReceiptAction> actions = new ArrayList<ReceiptAction>();
        ReceiptAction action = new ReceiptAction();
        S3Action s3Action = new S3Action();
        s3Action.setBucketName(mytestbucket);
        s3Action.setObjectKeyPrefix(customerIdString);
        action.setS3Action(s3Action);
        actions.add(action);
        rule.setActions(actions);
        req.setRule(rule);
        CreateReceiptRuleResult response = sesClient.createReceiptRule(req);
        return true;
    }
```

Whenever I add a customer I was calling this method to create a rule to my active ruleset. But it looks like only 100 rules can be added. My usecase will be for at least 100 000. How can I achieve this?

Something I am expecting to do is

1. Have a single recipient rule which says any email comes to mysubdomain invoke a lambda function
2. Lambda function should put the email into subfolders of s3

Comment: Is it possible to have a single ruleset for my domain and have a lambda function to put it into different folders inside the s3 bucket?

Comment: yes - you should have a single ruleset which puts ALL emails into a single S3 bucket (`unsorted_emails`), and then attach an event trigger on the bucket `unsorted_emails` which triggers a lambda function to move the emails into the necessary S3 buckets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to achieve what you desire...

1. Create a single SES rule to place ALL emails into a single S3 folder `unsorted_emails` (you can call it anything).
2. Create a Lambda function that places emails into their proper folders.
3. Set `unsorted_emails` as an event source to trigger your lambda function.
4. Now, whenever new emails are added to `unsorted_emails`, your lambda function will be triggered and move the email into a proper folder.

Let me know if these steps make sense, if you have any questions, or if I can clarify more.